# Checking if there is another username in db is not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication, registration

I have coded this in PHP and it works fine, it inserts my data from registration page to my database. It creates the account. I have tried to add a condition to check if the username already exists in the database, and if it does, i want to redirect him on to a new page saying that the username already exists. And if the username doesn't exist in the database, i want him to register normally. In my case, even if the username exists in the database it creates another one over the existing one. I have watched videos and read on the internet but i really can't understand how to do it. Sorry for my bad english and if i wasn't clear enough.

This is my code:

```
<?php 
session_start();
// Create connection
include('config.php');


if (isset($_POST['buton_inregistrare'])) {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
    $password2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password2']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
    $stergere = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['stergere']);
    $realName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['numeReal']);
    $security = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['seqcod']);
    
    $verUsername = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT login FROM account WHERE name='$username'");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($verUsername);
    if ($count > 0) {
        header("location: ../inregistrare_esec2.html");
    }

    //check if passwords are the same
    if ($password == $password2) {
    
        //Creating user
        $sql = "INSERT INTO account(login, password, email, social_id, real_name, securitycode) VALUES('$username', PASSWORD('$password'), '$email', '$stergere', '$realName', '$security')"; 
        mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        header("location: ../inregistrare_succes.html");
    }
    else{
        // passwords are not the same
        header("location: ../inregistrare_esec.html");
    }
        
    

}
```

?>

And this is how my mysql looks like:
[mysql image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDUu1.png)

Comment: $verUsername and $count  print_r this and seee output

Comment: You don't have `name` field in your table. `real_name` or `login` only.

Comment: @MrKhan, how do i do that?

Comment: @u_mulder i've changed this:
SELECT login FROM account WHERE name='$username
to this:
SELECT login FROM account WHERE login='$username
And it still creates user even if the username already exists